# Formatting the bibliographic references

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, lists

What should I change in order to make my bibliographic references (see latex code bellow), look like the ones attached in the form of image bellow? If you run the code you will see that

1. only the first line is aligned correctly from the left, and
2. the name of the journal contains lower case characters only whereas what I want is the very first character to be upper case and all the rest lower case as presented in the image bellow.

All suggestions are welcome.

[image]

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{document}
\citep{Dunham2002}
\bibliography{test.bib}
\end{document}
```

**test.bib**

```
@ARTICLE{Dunham2002,
   author = {M.H. Dunham},
   title = {\em Data Mining: Introductory and Advanced Topics},
   journal = {Prentice Hall},
   year = 2002,
}
```

Comment: You should provide a [**minimal** working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). You can remove the `\em` from the `title` field (or enclose the emphasized text with `\emph{<emph. text}`) --- remember that the bibliographic style file is in charge of styling elements. The first issue is solved with `\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}`, check [**natbib manual**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/natbib), §2.12

Comment: @henrique Thank you very much for helping me solve the first problem. What's your advice regarding the second one?

Comment: Your test.bib entry is somewhat wrong. The item is a `@book`, and Prentice Hall is the `publisher`. Can you please provide a better test case that shows the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple: the bibliographic entry should be announced as `@BOOK` and not `@ARTICLE`, with the right fields.

```
@BOOK{Dunham2002,
   author = {M.H. Dunham},
   title = {Data Mining: Introductory and Advanced Topics},
   publisher = {Prentice Hall},
   year = 2002,
}
```

[image]